# Computer shuts off at night and won't turn back on unless I play with it.

Tags: desktop

My desktop turns off when I'm sleeping and it won't turn back on unless I unplug the plug from the power supply or turn the switch off and back on. One of these combinations turns it back on. It stays on all day.

Answer (score 1):

Press Windows + R to open command prompt.

Type:  powercfg.cpl   and press return.

Change the Settings you want.